# using checkboxes in Laravel's Form::model

Tags: mysql, checkbox, laravel-4

I'm having trouble with Laravel's `Form::model()` construct. I was able to populate it with my model data but the checkboxes aren't being checked. The values are being set to 1 or 0 (courtesy of Eloquent calling a "boolean" a "tinyint" in MySQL), but I can't see how to use the `Form::model()` approach and set that checked attribute if the value coming is an integer and not a boolean (hence why I think [Form Model Binding for checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864626/form-model-binding-for-checkboxes) isn't working).

I'm specifying this in my view:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('hasDiscount') }}
```

And the form builder is returning this:

```
<input name="hasDiscount" type="checkbox" value="1" id="hasDiscount">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not really related to data-value. The value could be 'true' and the checked attribute could be false as well.

If you want to display checkbox with checked attribute, you can try my wait (it's not the best, I admit):

```
Form::model($model)
  Form::checkbox('name', null, $model->value)
Form::close()
```

The third parameter could be convert to false if the value of model is null or 0 and the checkbox is not checked. otherwise, it's checked.

If you have another idea, please share it.